# Can you make the z-axis be shown on the plane where models are being designed? It is only showing the X and Y axis

Tags: 3d-view

on the plane, only 2 of the axis are being shown. Can I also make the Z axis be shown?
When I model my designs, I also want to see the Z axis so that it will be easier to align when designing, and also properly scale my models

Comment: What plane? The one in Spain with all the rain? Show us your detail! 

Comment: You need to give more detail
What do u mean by z axis
the z axis overlay in viewport?
or the scale values in property panel
U havent provided any imformation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to expand the Viewport Overlays settings (The button on the right of the two intersecting circles in the top right of the interface) and there you can select which axes to display, on the very first line.

[image]